# Not able to understand relative velocity in 2dimension?

Tags: kinematics, coordinate-systems, vectors, relative-motion

[image]
I have a body A = 4j and B = -3i

Their relative velocity = -3i-4j.

But the position is somewhere they both don’t even meet.

It should be from B to A but it form C to A or B.Not able to understand what this mean ?

Comment: -3i - 4j is from the origin to C. (not A to C). It is equal (in direction and magnitude) to AB. If the graph shows velocities it will be a velocity as well; otherwise a displacement.

Answer (score 0):

-3i - yj is the velocity of B relative to A. It is the velocity of B as measured in a frame of reference in which A is stationary.

You are clearly representing velocities of A and B in your frame of reference by points on a grid. It is confusing to show the relative velocity, -3i - yj on the same axes that you have shown A and B, because the relative velocity is not a velocity in the same frame of reference as the velocities of A and B.

Comment: But we are talking about relative velocity here.How can it be relative displacement

Comment: I've changed my answer now I understand your question better.

Comment: Ok.I understood your point.

Comment: We can't tell, of course, whether or not A and B are going to meet, because we don't know their positions, only their velocities.

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that a body $A$ is moving in the right direction and you are in that body and there is another body $B$ and your friend is there now we will see that your freind is going back but in reality you are going forward.

From the above example we can conclude that whenever there is relative motion then the observer we feel that he is in rest position and the velocity vector of the observer will be given to the object but the direction is reversed.

Now in that which you have given the velocity vector of $A$ is $4\bf j$ and the velocity vector of $B$ is $-3\bf i$ now the velocity of $B$ wrt to A will be $- 3\bf i - 4\bf j$ and the velocity vector of $A$ wrt to $B$ is $4\bf j + 3\bf i$.

Comment: -3i - 4j is the RV of sth like the resultant vector.It is almost like an imaginary velocity.